# How are variables stored inside a class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, include

I made a slight progress with PHP. Recently I have been playing with classes and I realized there is something fundamental about variables that I probably don't understand.

I created 3 PHP files.

test1.php:

```
 <?php
class TEST{
    private $data;
    function setData($name, $value){
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
    function getData($name){
            return $this->data[$name];

    }
    function redirect($url){
        header("Location: $url");
    }
}

$test = new TEST();
```

test2.php

```
<?php
include("test1.php");
$test->setData("sample", "Will I work?");
$test->redirect("test3.php");
```

test3.php

```
<?php
include("test1.php");
echo $test->getData("sample");
```

The first file defines a class and creates an object. The second file includes the first file and uses a function inside this class to store value into the private variable "data", then redirects to the third file which again includes the first one and tries to retrieve this stored data, but it doesn't work. Both of the files are connected to the first one. One stores info into it and the other tries to access it. Yet it seems like they aren't connected at all.

What am I missing? This feels really basic and I am ashamed to say I have no clue why it doesn't work.

Comment: You have different instances of TEST on each of your page requests despite the variables/objects having the same name.

Answer (score 2):

PHP Variables are only stored so long as the page is active/doing something, and therefore when you redirect from page 2 to page 3, the content stored in that variable is eliminated. The only way to save content between pages is to save it into a session/cookie/database, and then reload the content from there. Simply including the first file means that you are capable of using the class, and its functions, but the data is eliminated as soon as you migrate away from Test2.php.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains it perfectly. I dont know why I felt like its all active thanks to the includes.

Comment: Not wanting to be a pendant but test2.php could still be be running after the redirect and load of test3.php (this is most unlikely but possible as test2.php continues to run in the example above).

Comment: @Jo.joe I think it's important to clarify that "include" isn't really all that special; it's equivalent to just writing out all the code of the included file. So you can think of `include("test1.php")` as simply saying "put the source code of test1.php right here". It doesn't include/transfer anything in memory -- such as variable values -- only the source code.

Answer (score 0):

**Classes** are programming language structures that define what class objects include in terms of data stored in variables also known as properties, and behavior of the objects defined by functions also known as methods.

**Objects** are containers. They contain the definition functions and variables that represent a single abstract entity.

Objects will be destructed (unloaded from memory) at the end of the page load, or if you unset all references to it earlier.

So for the objects and classes, the PHP variables persist for the lifetime of the script running through the interpreter. In the case of a web request, this is the lifetime of handling the requests.